# Rusting of iron pipes

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have a basketball support pole that is 5" in diameter welded from iron pipes that supports the hoop. There is a vertical component welded to a horizontal one that supports the backboard and hoop. The pole developed two rust holes approximately 1 1/2" in diameter in the horizontal section. Based on responses I have seen, rust cannot form without the presence of moisture and oxygen. Therefore, I sprayed an expansive foam to occupy the air voids within the pipe (only in the horizontal portion where the rust holes are). I sprayed a permatex rust neutralizer on the exterior location of the two holes. I plan on closing the holes with J B Weld (a very strong 2 part resin). Lastly, I will paint the poles with Rustoleum protective enamel paint. The thought is to seal the pipe from air and slow or discontinue the rusting process. I even considered spraying the pipe before painting with the rubberized Flex Seal to completely encapsulate the pipe. This may not be necessary but your opinion would be helpful. Please comment on the statements I have made in terms of accuracy and procedure. Thank you for your thoughts in advance.

Comment: Some DIY pages might be more useful than this site. It seems you are planning carefully and I guess your pole will last

Comment: You might try https://diy.stackexchange.com/ , since the question is not simply about chemistry *per se*. For example, can water/air enter under those coatings? What has been the actual experience in such repairs?